# Global ajax error handler, and closures

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm trying to wrap my head around a closure related issue.

I've set up a global error handler for jquery, using `$(document).ajaxError`, a simplified version is:

```
$(document).ajaxError(
function(event, xhr, settings, exceptionthrown)
    {
        LogError(settings.url, function() { $.ajax(settings); });
    }
);
```

`LogError` is a function which logs the error, and allows the user to retry the request (it calls the function passed in via the second param in the above example).

Everything is fine when there's only a single error, but when there are multiple errors, settings always points to a single object. I understand that this might be because:

a) All objects are passed by reference.
b) my callback function is grabbing settings from the ajaxerror params, the same object might be re-used for future errors?

Could anyone confirm what's going on, and how I would go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `settings always points to a single object`? It should return settings for the ajax call with error.

Comment: @Cheery: within the callback function, settings always points to the same object. If I have two ajax errors and two invocations of .ajaxError (with different settings.urls), when I retry the call using the callback function passed to LogError, they both retry a single URL (i.e, a single set of settings).

Comment: You probably have to show some more code. Did you check browser network logs for requests? May be you have the set of the same repeated requests.

Answer (score 1):

That works right:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some_url',
    success: function(){}
    });
$.ajax({
    url: '/some_other_url',
    success: function(){}
    });
$(document).ajaxError(
    function(event, xhr, settings, exceptionthrown)
    {
       alert(settings.url);
    }
);
```

Outputs: `/some_url` and `/some_other_url`

ps: with `$.ajax(settings);` added after alert it creates an infinite recursion with interleaving `/some_url` and `/some_other_url`. Which eats resources... If you have a delayed call of the second argument then try to write it as

```
$(document).ajaxError(
function(event, xhr, settings, exceptionthrown)
    {
        var sett = settings;
        LogError(settings.url, function() { $.ajax(sett); });
    }
);
```

Comment: @Kim Sun-wu Do you mean `function() { $.ajax(settings); })` ? but if something is not accessible it will create an infinite loop. What is the purpose?